# no required module provides package github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, sdk

Why am I getting this error message? I'm a beginner at using aws sam and Go.

```
Error: GoModulesBuilder:Build - Builder Failed: main.go:9:2: no required module provides package github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws; to add it:
go get github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws
main.go:10:2: no required module provides package github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session; to add it:
go get github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session
main.go:11:2: no required module provides package github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/dynamodb; to add it:<br>
go get github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/dynamodb
```

This is my code in vscode
package main

```
import (
    "logs"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/dynamodb"
)
```

Comment: What is the go version installed?

Comment: The error message is asking you to run a command.  Have you tried running it? If so, and if it didn't resolve the issue, did it give any errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set up your Go project properly for dependency management. First follow the steps for initializing the project as described in [Tutorial: Get started with Go](https://golang.org/doc/tutorial/getting-started):

```
go mod init YOUR_PROJECT_NAME
```

And then add your dependencies:

```
go get github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws
go get github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/dynamodb
```

Comment: After hours off reach i found out what the issue was. My go.mod file was a little dirty so i deleted it and rebuilt it.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that AWS SAM creates a folder structure where the root of the SAM project contains the `Makefile` where AWS has you build the executable, but the entry point of the application is in a sub-folder (i.e. the `hello-world` folder).

You must run `go mod init` and `go mod tidy` from the same location as the `main.go` and `go.mod` files, not from the root folder of your SAM application.

So for anyone else learning SAM with go, try changing to the sub-folder with your go files before you run go commands.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have go.mod file run the command below to find module for package xxx/xxx

```
go mod tidy
```

[Call code in an external package](https://golang.org/doc/tutorial/getting-started#call)

Answer (score 0):

For people with this problem using `AWS SAM` and `vs-code`, **if your folder look like this**:

```
├── Makefile
├── README.md
├── hello-world
│   ├── go.mod
│   ├── go.sum
│   ├── main.go
│   └── main_test.go
└── template.yaml
```

Try to **move** the `go.mod` and `go.sum` to the root folder (where the vs-code was opened), like this:

```
├── Makefile
├── README.md
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── hello-world
│   ├── main.go
│   └── main_test.go
└── template.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe late to the party, but kind of encounter this problem also.

I believe the problem more on the import path,
from the documentation every submodule is on `../aws-sdk-go/service/<sub-module-name`.

But the right one should be: `../aws-sdk-go/aws/<sub-module-name`

notice the `aws` instead `service`